# navigator.notification.alert unit test javascript

Tags: javascript, notifications, qunit

Here's my code...

```
navigator = {
    notification: function(text, function() {}, title, buttonName){
        alert("Cleared!");
    }
};
```

I'm getting an error on function.  I've also tried empty quotes and null.  None seem to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator = {
    notification: function(text, title, buttonName){
        alert("Cleared!");
    }
};
```

The above code should work better. In your function definition you must list variable names between the open and close parentheses. In your code example you used a function literal instead.

I would also recommend using a developer toolbar, such as Chrome Developer Tools to help you in debugging your JavaScript.

Best luck,